# Request Packet Generation Code in NS2 Tcl/Tk

Tags: amazon-s3, tcl, ns2, knox-amazon-s3-client

```
for {set i 0} {$i < $num_nodes} {incr i} {
   for {set j 0} {$j < 10} {incr j} {
     $ns at [expr 7.2+[expr rand()*3.0]] "$n($i) send_message 10 1 {[expr round([expr rand()*100000])]:[expr round([expr rand()*$numdata1])]:1:-1:-1} $MESSAGE_PORT"
     set generated1 [expr $generated1 + 1]
   }
}
```

I am building code for request packet generation in tcl ns2. i found these line from the internet, but I cannot understand this line:

```
$ns at [expr 7.2+[expr rand()*3.0]] "$n($i) send_message 10 1 {[expr round([expr rand()*100000])]:[expr round([expr rand()*$numdata1])]:1:-1:-1} $MESSAGE_PORT"
```

please tell me what is the logic behind these above lines?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that's bad use of nested `expr`. Cleaning that up:

```
 $ns at [expr {7.2+rand()*3.0}] "$n($i) send_message 10 1 {[expr {round(rand()*100000)}]:[expr {round(rand()*$numdata1)}]:1:-1:-1} $MESSAGE_PORT"
```

Looking at that word-by-word:

- `$ns`
- `at`
- `[expr {7.2+rand()*3.0}]`

  - a random float value between 7.2 and 10.2
- `"$n($i) send_message 10 1 {[expr {round(rand()*100000)}]:[expr {round(rand()*$numdata1)}]:1:-1:-1} $MESSAGE_PORT"`

  - a quoted string that is subject to variable and command substitutions (see the [Tcl(n)](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) man page)
  - looking further, we have:

    - `$n($i)` <== an associative array value at key `$i`
    - `[expr {round(rand()*100000)}]` <== a random integer between 0 and 100,000
    - `[expr {round(rand()*$numdata1)}]` <== a random integer between 0 and `$numdata1`

After Tcl substitutes all that, we might have something like

```
nsValue at 9.99934 "nValue send_message 10 1 {42:1234:1:-1:1} 8080"
```